# removing skype from my taskbar while i deleted skype

Tags: skype

I deleted skype for business, but there is still a taskbar from skype for business and i can´t close it . Doesn´t make sense. I have  already deleted it

I tried to close it.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: This question might work better on our sister site, SuperUser.

Comment: Which sister ste ? And should I ask a question once again on your site ?